# read blank input and even the numeric input

Tags: java, blank-line

I tried to make a coding about read the value o sign of numers,and also I have to include the blank space as input,I could read and identify the numers' value,but I could read the blank input and give the error (exception in thread "main" java.lang.numberformatexception: for input string: ")

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CheckingSign {
  public static void main (String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter floating point value: ");
        String number = scanner.nextLine();
        int n = Integer.parseInt(number);


              if ( n > 0 ) {
              System.out.print("DEBUG:the user input is <   " + number + "  >");
              System.out.println("DEBUG:the trimed input is <" + number + ">");
              System.out.println("The sign of the input is 1");
            } else if ( n < 0 ) {
              System.out.print("DEBUG:the user input is <   " + number + "  >");
              System.out.println("DEBUG:the trimed input is <" + number + ">");
              System.out.println("The sign of the input is -1");
            } else {
              System.out.print("DEBUG:the user input is <   " + number + "  >");
              System.out.println("DEBUG:the trimed input is <" + number + ">");
              System.out.println("Encountered blank input.");

            }
     }

}
```

Comment: `Enter floating point value` - For this, you need `float n = Float.parseFloat (number);` instead of `int n = Integer.parseInt (number);`

Comment: It still giving me the same error when I try to put blank space as input

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
        at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surround the `parse` with a `try-catch` statement

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter floating point value: ");
    String number = scanner.nextLine();
    
    try {
        
        float n = Float.parseFloat(number);
        
        if ( n > 0 ) {
          System.out.print("DEBUG:the user input is <   " + number + "  >");
          System.out.println("DEBUG:the trimed input is <" + number + ">");
          System.out.println("The sign of the input is 1");
        } else if ( n < 0 ) {
          System.out.print("DEBUG:the user input is <   " + number + "  >");
          System.out.println("DEBUG:the trimed input is <" + number + ">");
          System.out.println("The sign of the input is -1");
        }
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        
        System.out.print("DEBUG:the user input is <   " + number + "  >");
        System.out.println("DEBUG:the trimed input is <" + number + ">");
        System.out.println("Encountered blank input.");    
        
    }
```